# RequireJS: Difference between "requirejs" and "require" functions

Tags: javascript, requirejs, require

I am using requireJS 2.x. I found out that some tutorials (and the official docs) sometimes use

```
requirejs.config({ [...] });
requirejs(["module"]) ...
```

and sometimes

```
require.config({ [...] });
require(["module"]) ...
```

Is there any difference between those two functions (require and requirejs)? I could not find any word about that in the docs. :(

Answer (score 88, accepted):

They are exactly the same.

The reason is some environments might already have a `require`, in which case RequireJS doesn't overwrite it and allows usage of the library through `requirejs`

See this commit - https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/commit/be45948433b053921dc6a6a57bf06d04e13b3b39

Comment: Thanks :) That should be noted in the docs. The comments in the code don't make this clear.

Comment: I agree, it's confusing (and even the "official" requirejs page has inconsistencies between usage and the examples). Good to know they're one in the same.

Comment: Using CommonJS in the browser (via webpack or browserify) means that you can also access `requirejs` as `require` is already a local variable in tht situation. I have found this useful in React components to load additional scripts in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Good library, confusing documentation. Even the "API" section is not the API, but more of a "cookbook". There are lots of tutorials out there that are better to get started than the official docs.

Answer (score 20):

#### Are `requirejs` And `require` the Same?

As of RequireJS 2.1.15, `require` and `requirejs` in the global space are indeed "exactly the same", as can be evidenced by this test you can perform in the console:

```
> require === requirejs
true
```

That the test returns `true` tells you they are the *exact same function object*. They are not two functions that happen to have similar or identical code. They are the same object, period.

Note, however when you execute `define(['require'], function (require) {` The `require` passed to the function is normally *different* from the global `require`.

#### Should You Use `require` or `requirejs`?

It depends. RequireJS is an AMD loader but it is not the only loader in town. If you want to write code that conforms 100% to the [AMD spec](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD), so that someone using your code can use whatever loader they want without having to modify your code, then you should use `require` at the global level, because `requirejs` is specific to RequireJS. Another AMD loader won't define it. The AMD spec defines `require` but not `requirejs`.

If you are loading something else that defines a global `require` then you have to use `requirejs` at the global level to avoid conflict.

Inside a module, always use `define` to obtain a reference to `require`. You should do this quite irrespective of whether there is a conflict in the global space.

Answer (score 2):

OK, they may indeed be "exactly the same". Let's then focus on why you would use one versus the other...

What is unclear is what should be considered "best practice": If requirejs provides extra assurance "if some environments might already have a require", then wouldn't it be a good idea to always use the requirejs function to define a require configuration rather than the require function?

Also, what happens if the unthinkable happens and the environment in question not only already has a "require" defined but also has a "requirejs" defined? Does that mean we should have a requirejsjs too? And so on...?

Comment: Technically there are the same, just as `$` and `jQuery` are. It's just to provide a fallback and be a good citizen in case an environment already uses `require`. It's very much an edge case and it's recommended to use `require`, but not necessary - https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/AMD.md#global-variables-

Answer (score 0):

They are Same
Open website which loaded require already

then open Chrome console

type require in console and press enter

type requirejs in console and press enter

you can find that they are same function with different names